# Непонятная ошибка в работе цикла MySQL WHILE

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @c = 1 ;                        
SET @max_num = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM account);   

SET @Data_set = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()); 
SET @Data_unset = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) + 5184000;

WHILE @c < @max_num  DO
    INSERT INTO `account_premium`(`id`,`setdate`,`unsetdate`,`premium_type`,`active`) VALUES (@c, @Data_set,@Data_unset,'1','1');   
    SET @c = @c +1 ; 
END WHILE ;
```

Довольно простой для понятия запрос не работает, в чем косяк? Жалуется на цикл `WHILE`.

Comment: Если не сложно, просто приведите любой пример WHILE цикла.

Comment: Ну вот, например.

      mysql> delimiter //
      mysql> create procedure w (maxnum int)
          -> begin
          -> set @c=1;
          -> while @c <= maxnum do
          -> insert into tt (id) values (@c);
          -> set @c=@c+1;
          -> end while;
          -> end
          -> //
      mysql> call w (5);

Comment: если включить телепатор, то, скорее всего, id в таблице премиумов - foreign key на id таблицы пользователей. А в таблице пользователей некоторых id нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

зачем здесь вообще нужен цикл? все делается одним запросом.

```
INSERT INTO account_premium(id, setdate, unsetdate, premium_type, active)
SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 5184000, 1, 1 
FROM account
```

Comment: Спасибо. Цикл нужен был для общего познания